# Finding number of integer partitions with efficient way

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to find number of integer partitions of given n - number. If I have `n == 4`, the answer should be 5 because:

1. `4 = 1+1+1+1`
2. `4 = 2+1+1`
3. `4 = 3+1`
4. `4 = 2+2`
5. `4 = 4`

My code works properly but the matter is that it counts big numbers for a very long time. I have no idea how to optimize my code. Maybe you can help me to make it faster?

```
def get_answer(n):
    if n == 0:
        yield []
        return
    for p in get_answer(n-1):
        yield [1] + p
        if p and (len(p) < 2 or p[1] > p[0]):
            yield [p[0] + 1] + p[1:]
number_of_partitions=lambda n:sum(1 for _ in get_answer(n))
```

Comment: This might be better suited for CodeReview I think.

Comment: If you want to get it really fast, you should consider adding a [table](https://oeis.org/A000041).

Comment: @Mitch,  Elegant Python code for Integer Partitioning works slower than mine

Comment: @Nikita.K If you look a bit farther down on the linked duplicate, see http://jeromekelleher.net/generating-integer-partitions.html

Comment: @Mitch, I checked accel_asc. It works a bit faster but it takes more memory

Comment: @Nikita.K I encourage you to check out the CodeReview stack exchange site, it might be a good fit!